# How to see explicit paragraph markings in compiled document?

Tags: paragraphs

Sometimes I find it hard to keep track of where new paragraphs begin in my document. I have a lot of display equations and `\noindent` commands, as well as line breaks, blank lines, figures, etc. I can't tell precisely which of these elements are together in one paragraph.

Is there a way to see explicitly in my document (in the compiled pdf) where new paragraphs begin? I think this would be useful for debugging.

Comment: One way would be to remove the `\noindent` commands, which should be used extremely rarely in most documents, anyway.

Comment: If you can't tell where the paragraphs begin and end, how will your reader know?

Comment: @PaulGessler I use `\noindent` all the time, mostly after display equations which shouldn't start a new paragraph. Is there a different way to do that?

Comment: Paragraphs should simply be separated, in the input file, by a blank line. If you're using lots of explicit line breaks by ``\\`` and using lots of `\noindent`, you're on the wrong road. There should be no blank line after a displayed equation.

Comment: @becko if a new paragraph shouldn't be starting, then don't start one. (That is, don't leave a blank line in the source. If you want the whitespace for readability in your source, use comment characters to prevent a new paragraph.)

Comment: @egreg I usually insert a blank line after a display equation for better readability of the source tex file. Are you saying all my tex source should be contiguous??

Comment: @becko The problem has already been discussed here. ***No*** blank line should precede a displayed equation and usually no blank line should follow it, unless the equation ends the paragraph. If you want to visually detach the equation from the context in the input, use lines with just a `%` in them. A blank line between paragraphs is fine: indeed, it's the *best* way for separating paragraphs.

Comment: Can you show a typical chunk of text in your typing style?

Comment: @PaulGessler +1 Thanks, I suppose that's the better practice and I will do it from now on. However I'd still like an answer for the original question: Is there a way to see automatically generate paragraph markings in the compiled document?

Comment: +1 @egreg Thanks. (But I think you forgot to add a link?)

Comment: There are several questions about automated paragraph numbering. This question increments a counter using `\everypar`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208737/balancing-out-paragraph-indentation-after-one-and-two-digit-paragraph-numbers

Comment: It's not clear why you have a problem. In the source paragraphs are clearly marked by a blank line, and in the typeset result by a paragraph indent. If the paragraphs are not easily visible something is wrong, but you don't give any example so it is hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: I suspect this is really a duplicate but in view of your recent question on meta, closing it as dup probably isn't helpful at the moment so I expanded the above comments into a cw answer

Comment: How about `\everypar{\P}` after `\begin{document}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most document classes a paragraph start should be clearly visible in the output, marked by a section heading or a paragraph indent.

If this is not visually clear then essentially that is a failing in the typographic layout specified by the class. This is one of the objections to teh style of using no indentation and vertical separation for paragraphs as it typically makes it less clear where a paragraph starts.

Note that a blank line in the source file should never be used for cosmetic arrangement of the source file. It is parsed as a TeX instruction and creates the token `\par` exactly as if you typed `\par` explicitly. So a blank line should only be used in the source at the end of a paragraph.